# sorting highest to lowest prints contents as well and highest to lowest

Tags: sorting

```
viewclass= input("choose a class number and either alphabetically, average or highest?")


if viewclass=='1 alphabetically':#alphabetically
    with open('1.txt', 'r') as r:#sorting 
        for line in sorted(r):
             print(line, end='')#prints alphabetically

elif viewclass=='2 alphabetically':#alphabetically
    with open('2.txt', 'r') as r:#sorting 
        for line in sorted(r):
             print(line, end='')#prints alphabetically

elif viewclass=='3 alphabetically':#alphabetically
    with open('3.txt', 'r') as r:#sorting 
        for line in sorted(r):
             print(line, end='')#prints alphabetically



if viewclass=='1 highest':# sorting highest
    file = open("1.txt")#hihest to lowest code works in single and gives out put
    classj = (file.readlines())
    s = []
    for line in sorted(classj):
        classj = (line.rstrip())
        classa = (classj.split(":"))#sort
        score = int(classa[1])
        name = (classa[0])
        s.append( (name,score) )
        s.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x:x[1])
        for x in s:
            print(x[0],"-",x[1])#prints htl

elif viewclass=='2 highest':# sorting highest
    file = open("2.txt")#hihest to lowest code works in single and gives out put
    classj = (file.readlines())
    s = []
    for line in sorted(classj):
        classj = (line.rstrip())
        classa = (classj.split(":"))#sort
        score = int(classa[1])
        name = (classa[0])
        s.append( (name,score) )
        s.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x:x[1])
        for x in s:
            print(x[0],"-",x[1])#prints htl

elif viewclass=='3 highest':# sorting highest
    file = open("3.txt")#hihest to lowest code works  givesoutput
    classj = (file.readlines())
    s = []
    for line in sorted(classj):
        classj = (line.rstrip())
        classa = (classj.split(":"))#sort
        score = int(classa[1])
        name = (classa[0])
        s.append( (name,score) )
        s.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x:x[1])
        for x in s:
            print(x[0],"-",x[1])#prints htl
```

my code works alphabetically but when i ask for highest to lowest i get this

```
choose a class number and either alphabetically, average or highest?1 highest
Balsac  - 1# normal scores
Balsac  - 3
Balsac  - 1
Denzil  - 5
Balsac  - 3
Balsac  - 1
Denzil  - 5---- hihest to lowest
Balsac  - 3
Balsac  - 1
Ryan  - 1
Denzil  - 5
Balsac  - 3
Tim  - 2
Balsac  - 1
Ryan  - 1
```

does anyone know how i can just get this

```
Denzil  - 5
Balsac  - 3
Tim  - 2
Balsac  - 1
Ryan  - 1
```

Comment: Is this code written in Python?

Comment: It might useful to add a few more tags to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sure; move the sort/print code outside of the loop that is parsing the data; for example:

```
if viewclass=='1 highest':# sorting highest
    file = open("1.txt")#hihest to lowest code works in single and gives out put
    classj = (file.readlines())
    s = []
    for line in sorted(classj):
        classj = (line.rstrip())
        classa = (classj.split(":"))#sort
        score = int(classa[1])
        name = (classa[0])
        s.append( (name,score) )
    s.sort(reverse=True, key=lambda x:x[1])
    for x in s:
        print(x[0],"-",x[1])#prints htl
```